# DDD concept and bulk create

Tags: domain-driven-design

I'm learning DDD and I have a question.

Suppose there is a *Graph* entity with associated *Node* and *Edge* entities, corresponding to the vertices and edges of the graph. A node represents some business domain process, and an edge represents the interaction between processes.
There are some business logic rules. For example "Nodes has unique names in graph".
And there are 2 types of operations in the application:

1. Node and edge creation using REST API (for example POST /nodes/ and POST /edges/).
2. Import Graph data with all nested entities.

Logically, Graph is the root aggregate, and Node and Edge should be created and modified using it.
But then 2 questions arise:

1. To implement a REST API, do I **really** need to read all nested graph edges (there could be about 10,000 of them) from the DB in order to create or update just 1 object and check the necessary business logic invariants?
2. Suppose, after all, there is some kind of EdgeCreateService service created within the REST API, which performs business logic checks and creates a new record. Then, when implementing Graph import operation, you will have to process all records through this service in order to perform business logic checks and not break DRY.

It's possible to create *EdgeCreateService* which accepts an IRepository interface containing the necessary methods to perform business logic checks. For example, `IRepository.get_nodes_by_name(...)` to check the uniqueness of nodes names inside EdgeCreateService. And 2 implementations of this interface: *DBRepository* (for REST API) and *InMemoryRepository* (for import). But in this case, it turns out that the work is not done using the root aggregate. And this contradicts DDD.

Can someone tell what is the right thing to do in this case?

Comment: This doesn’t sound like a typical business domain. Why do you think the DDD tactical patterns are a good fit for this problem space?

Comment: That said, it’s advised to always design at least two different models to solve the same problem. That forces you to think outside of the box and could lead to a better model than what might seem most logical at first.

Comment: How do you intend to enforce a unique name for all nodes of a graph as a business rule, while being unwilling to look at all of the nodes (and therefore their names) when creating a new node? That's not a rhetorical question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to handle business rules that are "uniqueness" constraints?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/386671/how-to-handle-business-rules-that-are-uniqueness-constraints)

Comment: @RikD 
1. I have greatly simplified the description of the domain so that the question is brief and so as not to reveal what may fall under the NDA. In reality, there are more rules, as well as entities. The described entities are key to the project and business problems are solved with their help.
2. Could you clarify your point about the "two models"? Are you suggesting to duplicate validation of business rules in REST API service and in import service?

Comment: @Flater I forgot to add that currently import occurs with the creation of a new graph. That is, to answer your question, during import, uniqueness can only be checked using the data that is in the import file.

Comment: @guillaume31 thanks for link, but it does not answer my question. I wrote about checking uniqueness as an example and to shorten the question. In this application, there are more complex rules, for example that between two nodes there cannot be edges of the same type (type is an attribute of edges) or, for example, that when creating an edge with a certain type, you must also create an edge with the opposite direction and the certain type. I added some information to the question about what vertices and edges are. I am limited by NDA, unfortunately.

Comment: I meant two (or more) different domain models. Don’t take for granted that Graph should be the aggregate root. Explore other ways to tackle the business problems. Btw. what you’re facing here is what Khorikov calls the DDD trilemma in his blog, it might be useful to read: https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/posts/domain-model-purity-completeness/

Comment: @DenisNikanorov The additional invariants you mentioned probably belong more at the Node level or in a domain service than at the Graph level. Also, graphs being a well-studied computer science subject matter, there is probably already a proven optimal way to do it. As the first comment suggests, DDD might not be the right tool for the job here.

Comment: @RikD thanks for link! Seem there is no "right" answer to this question..

Answer (score 1):

Eventually I found this article by Vladimir Khorikov about a similar problem https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/posts/ddd-bulk-operations/.

It partially answer my question, but solution is quite complicated.

Also this article was helpful (thanks @Rik D) https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/posts/domain-model-purity-completeness/

Comment: Please describe the content of the links you provide. In case those links die, the information might get lost.